# According to comic book canon, how many full scale, full bodied Kryptonian humanoids made it to Earth?

Tags: dc, history, krypton

According to comic book canon, how many full scale, full bodied Kryptonian humanoids made it to Earth? Krypto, being non humanoid, of course wouldn't make the list, and neither would any Kandorians (Kandoites?) that never left the sanctuary of their jarred city.

I don't need a person by person hard count. An answer that includes instances of named individuals and/or groups with nameless background individuals would suit me fine.

I'd ask the same of the movies, but that tally could be determined in one(?) film, so it seems too basic to ask.

Comment: Present reboot only?

Comment: I'm an old school DC fan, and that's the answer I had in mind. If you posted a reboot version of the question,  It would be O.K. with me.

Comment: That's... a lot of continuity.

Comment: Loads and loads. There's his own "[family](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/marvel_dc/images/a/af/Superman_Family_Silver_Age_001.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20120622210722)" as well as the [six million or so Kandorians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kandor) (now full-sized) who survived in their bottle city and the inhabitants of [Fort Rozz](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Fort_Rozz)